# Running Remote Bamboo Agents on Demand Using Docker

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm trying to see if it would be viable to automatically spin up Bamboo containers for a CI build enviroment

Ideally I want any number of random containers to be able to spin up automatically and destroy themselves for a build without having to do any tinkering on the remote server with docker compose.

We have tons of different projects with different mishmashes of dependencies. So when a dev runs a build, my goal is that a container specific to that build should come up, add itself to the list of viable remote agents, run that build, and than destroy itself.

Has anyone tried anything similar or have any advice to see if this is viable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working for a while with Bamboo and remote agents on Docker and I happened to have tried to achieve to same thing. To simply answer your question : **No, this is not viable in my opinion**.
What you are trying to do is basically what Atlassian calls elastic agents but it only works for AWS for now.

In the current situation there is no way to spawn new agents when a build is queued. However, what you can do is to setup a first stage for each of your plans that will start the Docker container needed to perform the second stage. Your next stage will need to have Bamboo dependencies set so that only the Docker container you have spawned would be able to take care of it.

While this would work, let me tell you what flaw you should expect by doing this :

- Next stages will be ran inside a Docker container, killing the container itself at the end of your build will lead to a Bamboo build failure. You can do it in a last stage ran from an agent on the host but if your build fails for some reason you will never get to that stage
- Concurrency build and error checking will be far more difficult to handle

What we ended up doing where I work was just to pay for a license allowing more agents and ran them in their own Docker container for more agent isolation. You can expect to loose more money by wasting your time setting up such system than to just pay for more agents.

If your problem is less about money and more about having to deal with lots of different configuration, you can consider running Docker container at the beginning of a stage and forward all the command to it using `docker exec`. This will still not be easy to set up though.

Comment: The issue isn't money, just the need to support a different mishmash of different versions of JDK, node, php, (and in one specific case, OS version). Some devs build with global npm modules that I don't want to clutter up the build agent server, also it just seems messy to have a static container for every possible type of dependancy.

I was also thinking if it would be possible to have a env variable that would be set at build time to pass into the container to set the versions of application of that container to the required one through a symlink. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: That would work. But again it would take a lot of time to set up and maintain. How much different configuration do you have ?
I also think is it messy to have static container for every possible type of dependency. I look forward for Bamboo to enable elastic agents on more platforms (Docker swarm, openstack...)

Comment: Ideally I need to support 3 versions of node, 3 versions of java, 3 versions of php, and also those 3 versions of node on Centos6.

It's extremely messy so I'm trying to figure out how the hell I'm supposed to set up this build environment,

Comment: Given the current system you are supposed to go with one agents per environment but I understand you can feel  lack of flexibility. To me, your only option  is to go with what I propose in my answer. Add a first stage to all your plan that will detect your environment and run a new Docker container accordingly. Then all the following plans would exec command in this container with `docker exec`. You will need to be very careful to have the necessary final task to stop your container in case an error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

We (Atlassian Build Engineering) have created a set of plugins to run a number Docker based agents in a cluster (ECS) that come online, build a single job and then exit. It should be able to do what you desire. We've recently open sourced the solution.

See https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/per-build-container for more details.

Comment: i am trying to use that plugin but failing. @mkleint can you provide a way to contact you for resolving some issues with this setup?

Comment: sure, please use mkleint@atlassian.com or use issue tracking at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/per-build-container

Comment: Can this be expanded upon?  Asked a similar question as this question is related but closed. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641125/how-do-i-run-a-containerized-bamboo-remote-agent-on-demand?noredirect=1#comment109063567_61641125)

Comment: the uptodate information should be present on the website linked about. we are still running the setup successfully internally at atlassian. for a few years now on top of a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why Docker is great for CI builds, you have a bamboo agent reside on a server, which has access to the Docker binary.  Within your build script you pull, create, run, and destroy any version of whatever Docker image you need to run.  e.g. Needing to run tests against various versions of Node would only require that you have the directory checked out, then a

docker pull/run node:0.X -> collect tests

docker pull/run node:4.X -> collect tests

docker pull/run node:6.X -> collect tests

This is effectively how we run builds at our company.  I wrote about our setup sometime ago: http://blog.brianmkelley.com