# How do I run a containerized Bamboo remote agent on demand?

Tags: docker, bamboo

We currently have multiple Linux systems configured as static dedicated remote agents for our Bamboo project and want to move to using containerized remote agents that are spun up on demand.  How can this be done?  I see a containerized remote agent but where does this go?

We have containerized our build environment but the remote agent is still running on the dedicated hardware.  We want to remove all our dedicated remote agent machines and run everything in containers.  I'm an end user with no access to the server so not sure how I can accomplish this.  From what I've read probably not in the cloud so guessing an on-prem cluster?  New to this concept.

Comment: Can you talk more about what you have already tried that does not work? This question currently reads like "how do I scale my build architecture?" which isn't very focused.

Comment: @AndyShinn Updated but you're correct because I have no experience with this but been tasked to develop a plan on how to accomplish it.  I think it is focused but on a high level concept more than a lower level, finite x+y=z problem.  
I see things about clusters, kube and such but no understanding of the interactions.  All my experience is working with static remote agents in a client/server setup.  The agent is up 24/7 to answer requests.  If the agent is not running how does the process start?  What starts the remote agent? And all within a very short timeframe which is why I'm asking here

Comment: Here is the [previous question for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600978/how-do-i-run-a-bamboo-remote-agent-in-a-docker-container). I fear this is a (shorter) duplicate.

Comment: I see this the same as [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828483/running-remote-bamboo-agents-on-demand-using-docker).  Being over 4 years old I assume things have progressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bamboo provides a per-build_container plug-in for this.  The cluster is specified as part of the configuration and the containerized remote agent (sidekick) is specified in the build job and spins up with the job starts.  Based on documentations this can be AWS ECS, Docker cluster or Kubernetes.